# Setting up PPPoE on Debian 10 guidance

Tags: debian, networking, command-line, internet

I am trying to connect to the internet via PPPoE on my laptop running Debian 10 using the command line. Here is what I tried so far:

edit `/etc/ppp/provider` and add the following content:

```
plugin rp-pppoe.so enp4s0

# login settings
user "debian"
password "newbie"

# Connection setings
persist
maxfail 0
holdoff 6

# LCP settings
lcp-echo-interval 10
lcp-echo-failure 5

# PPPoE compliant settings
noaccomp
default-asyncmap
mtu 1492

# IP settings
noipdefault
defaultroute
```

run `sudo pon provider`

run

```
sudo plog

Sep 28 20:54:22 mars pppd[25650]: PPP session is 49123
Sep 28 20:54:22 mars pppd[25650]: Connected to cc:46:d6:fa:36:81 via interface enp4s0
Sep 28 20:54:22 mars pppd[25650]: Using interface ppp0
Sep 28 20:54:22 mars pppd[25650]: Connect: ppp0 <--> enp4s0
Sep 28 20:54:25 mars pppd[25650]: EAP-TLS: Error: client name not set (BUG)
Sep 28 20:54:25 mars pppd[25650]: Connection terminated.
Sep 28 20:54:25 mars pppd[25650]: Sent PADT
```

I looked at the network traffic in wireshark during the discovery phase and saw that the password field is empty.

Do I have to use the `/etc/ppp/pap-secrets` or `/etc/ppp/chap-secrets` file for the username and password. What is the difference between those two files?
What does the first line in `/etc/ppp/provider` mean? What kind of plugin is this? Is there a documentation for the `/etc/ppp/privider` config file?

Where is the difference between ppp, pppoe and pppoeconf? Do I need all of them or am I mixing things up?

A practical guide on how to set up a PPPoE connection on Debian would be nice.

Thanks in advance.

Best wishes!
Leon

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://wiki.debian.org/PPPoE) is a link to the Debian Wiki on PPoE configuration.
[Here](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch05.en.html#_the_ppp_connection_with_pppconfig) is a link to the Debian Networking Manual.
And lastly, [here](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/PPP-HOWTO/) is a link to a comprehensive (albeit dated) Linux PPP guide.

Now, for your questions:

> Do I have to use the `/etc/ppp/pap-secrets` or `/etc/ppp/chap-secrets` file for the username and password. What is the difference between those two files?

If your PPP provider requires authentication then you need to use one or the other of those files using the username and password they provide you with. `/etc/ppp/pap-secrets` and `/etc/ppp/chap-secrets` are for Password Authentication Protocol (PAP) and Challenge Handshake Authentication Protocol (CHAP) authentication configurations, respectively. [This](https://tldp.org/LDP/nag/node120.html) site goes over the differences. Basically, PAP works by sending the username and password over the wire and CHAP works by regularly sending a "challenge" string to additionally authenticate against. You will have to have the one your provider uses configured appropriately.

> What does the first line in `/etc/ppp/provider` mean? What kind of plugin is this? Is there a documentation for the `/etc/ppp/provider` config file?

`plugin rp-pppoe.so enp4s0` is activating the kernel module for PPPoE for the specified network interface. This is a Kernel plugin necessary for PPPoE usage. I cannot seem to find documentation that directly references what `/etc/ppp/provider` should have in it but it looks like `pppoeconf` should create the file by default, or you at least need to but the minimum amount of details necessary for PPPoE in it. Please refer to the links provided for more information.

> Where is the difference between ppp, pppoe and pppoeconf? Do I need all of them or am I mixing things up?

PPP is Point to Point Protocol which provides a standard way to establish
a network connection over a serial link. On Debian this is the `pppd` or PPP Daemon. PPPoE is Point to Point Protocol over Ethernet, so the PPP frames are handled inside Ethernet frames. `pppoeconf` is a Debian provided tool for configuring PPPoE connections.

As pointed out in the [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/PPPoE):

> Run pppoeconf to generate and/or modify /etc/ppp/peers/dsl-provider, /etc/ppp/*ap-secrets files and /etc/network/interfaces. It is best, in most cases, to keep the suggested answers.

The first 2 are protocols, and the last one is a Debian tool for configuring the protocol, PPPoE.

I believe between all the links provided, you should be able to find a comprehensive guide to PPPoE on Debian. Effectively, you run the setup script (`pppconf` or `pppoeconf`) and answer the following questions to enable PPP networking for your system:

- The telephone number
- The ISP user name
- The ISP password
- The port speed
- The modem communication port
- The authentication method

You are most likely using PPPoE so some of these questions do not apply. Please refer to your ISP for additional assistance if necessary.

Best of Luck!

Comment: A bit later, but I want to comment on the question "Where is the difference between ppp, pppoe and pppoeconf?". While you're right that ppp and pppoe are protocols, I more think that the original question was about the Debian packages named as such. Yes, all 3 names are valid packages. "ppp" is definitely needed as it contains the ppp package, but between pppoe and pppoeconf it's a bit hard to decide. My investigation says that "pppoe" is old and shouldn't be used (was before pppoe kernel module), and today only pppoeconf is needed. HTH!